# How to "post" an image and data that has strings and ints

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to upload images through a post rest api. The only successful way in the past to upload images that I've found was to use `MultipartRequest`, however when i use :

```
var request = new MultipartRequest("POST",uri)
request.fields.addAll(apiMapData);
request.files.addAll(apiMapImages);
```

I run into the problem that the fields is required to be a `Map<String,String>` however the API expects me to send some integer values so my map is `<String,dynamic>`. Is there any idea how can i get around that?

Comment: url-encoded form data and by extension multipart form data must be in the form of strings. If you need to add an integer to form, simply convert it to a string first - `someInt.toString()`

Comment: if you are writing the server. why not upload the image as base64 string.
make it all way simpler.

anyway. by my understanding, there is no way to add other than a string parameter in a multipartRequest ( even in postman )

Comment: @RichardHeap I need them to be ints since the db/api requires them to be so, they are declared as ints.

Comment: @AloneBashan I'm not really writing them but a friend of mine is. I'm a Frontend developer only. However last time we tried base64 the images wouldn't upload for some reason. I tried a lot until we finally switched to MultipartRequest

Comment: sounds like there must be a little server modify. accept String and convert it to Int

Comment: Alright sounds good, will try the base64 one last time I guess, if not will modify backend to convert or accept strings. Thanks!

Comment: Just put your integers as strings......

Comment: @Antoniossss U can't send them as strings if the db is expecting ints....

Comment: You are sending string over HTTP. Database have less than nothing to do with this.

Comment: The api returns error code 500 if you try that.